# input parameters on C++ file to a global variable

Tags: c++, libpqxx

I'd like to feed a global variable some external parameters.

My actual code is:

```c
    static const char conn_str[] =
    "user='postgres' password='' host='127.0.0.1' port='5432' dbname='database'";
    
    pqxx::connection C(conn_str);
    pqxx::nontransaction N(C);
```

And I'd like to be able to feed the code with argv parameters and still using connection C as global.

Any thoughts?
thanks in advance...

## changes made:

```c
    //I initialized 
    static const char conn_str[][150]="";

    pqxx::connection* C(conn_str);
    pqxx::nontransaction* N(C);

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    
    // code (....)
    
    database=argv[4];
    char data[]="dbname=%s user=postgres hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432";
    sprintf(conn_str,database);
    C = new pqxx::connection(conn_str);
    N = new pqxx::nontransaction (C);

    OpenPSQL();
    LoadHeader ();
    LoadCustomers ();
    LoadProducts ();
    LoadTaxes ();
    
    // code
    
    delete C;  //dont forget to delete it when you are done
    delete N;  //dont forget to delete it when you are done
    }
```

I got errors such:

> main.cpp: In function ‘void OpenPSQL()’:
>
> main.cpp:268: error: request for member ‘is_open’ in ‘C’, which is of non-class type ‘pqxx::connection*’

Answer (score 0):

Use pointers something like this:

```
static const char conn_str[];
pqxx::connection* C;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   //... feed conn_str with argv here
   C = new pqxx::connection(conn_str);
   //... do whatever needs to be done
   delete C;  //dont forget to delete it when you are done
}
```

Comment: change this line to the following, you are using a pointer so point to it:
N = new pqxx::nontransaction (*C);

Answer (score 0):

You've changed `C` from an object to a pointer, so you'll need to change member accesses from `C.whatever` to `C->whatever` if you really want to take that approach. The compiler is complaining that you're applying `.` instead of `->` to a pointer.

A better approach would be move the variables themselves into `main`, and pass them by reference to whichever functions need them. Then their lifetime is automatically managed and the dependencies are clearly visible. Global variables are almost never a good idea.

Also, use `std::string` instead of a fixed-size buffer, so you don't get an overflow if the command-line argument is too long.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see there's a long path to make this code more reliable.